# Dynamically generated table content (using XSLT) has single quote ( ' ) in it and JavaScript throws Uncaught syntax error

Tags: javascript, xslt

Sample **XML** is as below.

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <AssetType>Theme Article</AssetType>
    <Name>The State</Name>
    <Theme>Family</Theme>
    <DateAdded>2017-08-06T17:43:04</DateAdded>
    <ActivationDate>2017-06-04T00:00:00</ActivationDate>
    <ExpirationDate>2018-05-01T00:00:00</ExpirationDate>
    <Owner>Testing Owner</Owner>
    <SiteCount>18796</SiteCount>
    <Sites>
      <Site>
        <SiteName> XYZ</SiteName>
        <SiteUrl>https://sample.com/test/</SiteUrl>
      </Site>
      <Site>
        <SiteName>ABC O'Brian</SiteName>
        <SiteUrl>https://sample1.com/test/</SiteUrl>
      </Site>

    </Sites>
   </Item>
</Items>
```

I am using **XSLT** to display the items and using **Data Table** collapsible button to return the inner xml contnet, Sitename and SiteUrl. But throwing exception when content having single quote ' in it.

```
    function format ( d ) { 
    var a='<div class="row-fluid_SiteUrl">' +
        '<div class="span12">' +
            '<table data-datatable="dynamic" data-mybuttons="copy,excel,pdf,print" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="esSiteUrlResultsTbl">'+
    '<thead>'+
      '<tr>'+
        '<th>Site Name</th>'+
        '<th>Site URL</th>'+
      '</tr>'+
    '</thead>'+
    '<tbody>';

    var b= '<xsl:for-each select="Items/Item/Sites/Site">'+
            '<tr>'+
                '<xsl:variable name="Siteurl"><xsl:value-of select="SiteUrl"/></xsl:variable>' +
                '<td><xsl:value-of select="SiteName"/></td>'+
                '<td><a href="{$Siteurl}"><xsl:value-of select="SiteUrl"/></a></td>'+
            '</tr>'+
        '</xsl:for-each>';

var c="</tbody>"+
  "</table>"+
"</div>"+
"</div>";

    return a+b+c;    
}
```

Sample output with Uncaught syntax error.

```
  '<tr>'+
    '' +
     '<td>ABC - O'Brien Jr., George</td>'+
     '<td><a href="https://Sample.com/">https://sample.com//</a></td>'+
    '</tr>'+
```

Comment: Using Javascript to generate XSLT is a little unusual. Is this really the best way to solve your problem? It seems far more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't indicated where/how you want to use that string the Javascript function `format` returns as XSLT and I doubt you will be able to use such a snippet without some context but in terms of Javascript you simply need to make sure you use single quotes `'` to delimit your string literals and then double quotes `"` inside for HTML or XML attribute delimiters. That way you at least shouldn't get a Javascript syntax error:

```
function format ( d ) { 
    var a='<div class="row-fluid_SiteUrl">' +
        '<div class="span12">' +
            '<table data-datatable="dynamic" data-mybuttons="copy,excel,pdf,print" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="esSiteUrlResultsTbl">'+
    '<thead>'+
      '<tr>'+
        '<th>Site Name</th>'+
        '<th>Site URL</th>'+
      '</tr>'+
    '</thead>'+
    '<tbody>';

    var b= '<xsl:for-each select="Items/Item/Sites/Site">'+
            "<tr>"+
                '<xsl:variable name="Siteurl"><xsl:value-of select="SiteUrl"/></xsl:variable>' +
                '<td><xsl:value-of select="SiteName"/></td>'+
                '<td><a href="{$Siteurl}"><xsl:value-of select="SiteUrl"/></a></td>'+
            '</tr>'+
        "</xsl:for-each>";

var c="</tbody>"+
  "</table>"+
"</div>"+
"</div>";

    return a+b+c;    
}
```

If you don't need to support IE then these days using back ticks as string literal delimiters might make it easier to put XML or HTML snippets into Javascript string literals.

Comment: I have updated my question with complete information. Please have a look and requesting your help.